# Embassy stamped the last (empty) page of the passport

Tags: visas, passports, ireland

I have recently received a visa from Ireland. I have just noticed that they stamped the very last blank page with the embassy stamp (it says "Embassy of Ireland" and has the location of the mission). The last page contains no other marks, and the page with the visa has another stamp at the expected place.

I am puzzled by this. Why would they do that? Am I in any sort of trouble for having improper markings in my travel document?

I am also somewhat worried this makes it look as if I was refused a visa. I do have **a** visa, but it is not immediately obvious that it was my only application.

[image: Visa page]
[image: Last page]

Comment: It would be helpful if you uploaded images of both, with your personal details blacked out of course. Otherwise we have to guess from collective experience as to what you are referring.

Comment: @Ozzy Good point, added.

Comment: One more question, did the embassy keep your passport while it was being processed or had you bring it in to place the visa sticker?

Comment: Yes, the passport was sent to the embassy for the entire processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, this is usually done when you get to keep your passport while they process the application. But generally in these cases the embassy takes the precautionary step of stamping your passport with their seal to show the application was taken in for processing. This is so that they may identify whether or not this was the passport originally presented to them.

Weird, but I am assuming this was also the case here.

No need to worry about any issues, refusals are stored in the VIS. If they have any doubts they will consult the system and see you are clear. See the [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144380/what-information-is-contained-in-the-schengen-visa-information-system-vis) for what is added to VIS file when you have a visa refused/granted.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring and also worth adding to the answer. Not accepting it now, but I'll update you when I get some authorative opinion (e.g. pass border control... assuming I will, lol).

Comment: Well noted and have edited!

Comment: All right, I haven't encountered any issues so this is probably the right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Norrius Glad everything went well!